# FB Connect going in an infinite loop with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

I am having the following php code which i am trying for testing FB Connect

```
<?php 
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'YOUR_APP_ID');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');
```

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
  enter code here $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($*COOKIE['fbs*' . $app_id], '\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
    <?php if ($cookie) { ?>
      Your user ID is <?= $cookie['uid'] ?>
      <br /> Your Acess Token is 
      <br />
    <?php
        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
        $cookie['access_token']));
        if($user) {
            echo "<br />Display Name = " . $user->name;
            echo "<br />First Name = " . $user->first_name;
            echo "<br />Last Name = " . $user->last_name;
            echo "<br />Birthday = " . $user->birthday;
            echo "<br />Home Town = " . $user->hometown->name;
            echo "<br />Location = " . $user->location->name;
            echo "<br />Email = " . $user->email . "<br />";
        }
    ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>

```
<div id="fb-root">&lt;/div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
           cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
</script>
```

</body>
</html>


The problem faced by me is it works fine with IE and Firefox, however when done the same with google chrome I am running into an infinite loop when I click on reload/refresh button of chrome after logging in.

Any hints as to why is it happening with chrome? Also how can it be avoided.

Thanks, 
Mitesh

Comment: Probably it's referred to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/239

Answer (score 0):

Should be work.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
    appId: 'APP_ID',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
    window.location.reload()
})
};
(function () {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e)
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

i think this is the problem, try to remove it.
i doesn't really need it though, coz i use this, and it automaticly refresh once when login

```
FB.login(function(response) {
if(response.session)
{
window.location.reload();
}
},{perms:’email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location’});
```